# How to share local Postgres database with docker?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a django project with PostgreS database. I need to use my local database in docker container. How to share localhost of the machine with docker container? My ***docker-compose.yml*** :

```
  version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      build: ./
      network_mode: "host"
      command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --i rest_framework && gunicorn orion-amr.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=2"
      ports:
        - "${webport}:8000"
        - "${pgport}:${pgport}"
      env_file:
        - ./.env
```

Django ***settings.py***:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('pgdatabase'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('pguser'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('pgpassword'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('pghostname'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('pgport'),
    }
}
```

I added

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

to ***postgresql.conf*** file and below is my ***pg_hba.conf*** file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::/0                    trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Now I have an error:

```
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  |
```

Who can help me? Please!

Comment: @mulg0r unfortunately, nothing changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

seems like `os.environ.get('pghostname')` pointing to `127.0.0.1` where `127.0.0.1` mean this container, not the Host DB. As the error

```
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
```

To connect with host DB you have special DNS for mac and window `host.docker.internal`. DB host should be

```
'HOST': "host.docker.internal"
```

To connect with HOST DB, or if you are on Linux then it should be

```
'HOST': "HOST_IP"
```

You can get host IP from `ifconfig`.

Comment: Thank you! Changed to host.docker.internal. This worked.